# Showing a distance function is a metric.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have the show that the distance function $d_0(x,y)=\max_{1\leq k\leq n}\ |x_k-y_k|$ is a metric.

I showed the triangle inequality as follows:

$d_0(x,z)=\max_{1\leq k\leq n}\ |x_k-z_k| \leq \max_{1\leq k\leq n} |x_k - y_k + y_k - z_k| \leq \max_{1\leq k\leq n} (|x_k - y_k| + |y_k - z_k|) \leq \max_{1\leq k\leq n} |x_k - y_k| + \max_{1\leq k\leq n} |y_k - z_k| = d_0(x,y) + d_0(y,z)$

I showed symmetry as follows:

$d_0(x,y) =\max_{1\leq k\leq n}\ |x_k-y_k|=\max_{1\leq k\leq n}\ |y_k-x_k|=d_0(y,x)$

I'm unsure how to show positivity. I have the following:

If $x=y$, then $x_k=y_k$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$. Hence $\max_{1\leq k\leq n}\ |x_k-y_k|=0$. If $\max_{1\leq k\leq n}\ |x_k-y_k|=0$, then each term must be $0$ since the maximum is $0$ and each term cannot be negative.

Is this a valid proof? If not, how can I fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Positivity: You are taking maximum of finitely many non-negative numbers. For the definiteness part: If the maximum is zero then all the absolute values inside are zero.

Comment: This is just the $L_\infty$ metric

Comment: This is good and correct.  But me being nitpicky, I'd like to have it pointed out that if each $x_k = y_k$ then $x = y$ (which is a big, "well, duh" but I'd still like to see it stated) and I'd like to say an argument if $d_0(x,y)\ne 0$ then it is greater than one.  And a real value.  I can't really criticize you for assuming these are obvious (as they are) but it should be stating that they are what must be demonstrated to be a metric.

Comment: As long as I am being picky, you should probably state that you are attempting to define this metric on $\mathbb R^n$.  If we don't know the space, none of this actually makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown every part correctly except:

What you called positivity was actually $$d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y $$ Which is good.

You still need to show that $$ d(x,y) \ge 0 $$ for all $x$,$y$.

Complete the proof by showing  $$ d(x,y) \ge 0 $$ for all $x$,$y$.